# How to use locale from Numeral.js in react-native?

Tags: react-native, numeral.js

I want to change currency format in Numeral.js with another country. How to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Did you manage to solve that problem?

I needed to use with pt-br and I did it:

```
import Numeral from "numeral";
import "numeral/locales/pt-br";

// switch between locales
Numeral.locale('pt-br');

//Usage
Numeral(100).format("$0.00")
// output R$100,00
```

Comment: It works partially. You need to set a mask, like this:  Numeral(100).format("$#,##0.00");

Comment: I didn't solve my problem yet, people who serve the data change it to fixed value (returning with full format) a week after I asked here, so I'm not using Numeral.js anymore. Is this answer works well? Considering to accept this..

Comment: is there any solution for Indian currency! I have wasted 3 hours on it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following;

//import

```
import Numeral from "numeral";
```

//use

```
numeral("10").value()
```

Answer (score 0):

Numeral.js v. 2.0.6

```
import numeral from 'numeraljs';

<Typography>$ {numeral(3000).format('0,0')} pesos</Typography>
```